# Global.asax.cs file in WCF Service

Tags: wcf, global-asax

I have got a WCF Service on IIS (bin, Service.svc, web.config).
And I want to use Global.asax.cs file.

So this is a problem

I tried 2 ways:

1) Using **aspnet_compiler.exe** : it gives me some files and when I put it to IIS, my procedure in Global.asax.cs file is works! But, Service1.svc file looks strange and do not work! So I cant use my service

2) Just put 3 files (bin, Service.svc, web.config) on IIS , Service1.svc looks good, it works, but Global.asax.cs doesn't work!

How can I use Global.asax.cs file in service?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You aren't using visual studio for this?

Comment: If I use VS 2008 for this - it's works normal, but I need without VS(just copy service's files to IIS)

Comment: Build your project in Visual Studio, right click the project and select "Publish...", set publishing to file system to some temp folder, and when its done copy everything in the temp folder to designated IIS folder for your application, publishing should put togather everything that is required to run the app.